# HEX to bit[ ] array (also known as bool[ ])

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, hex, bit

I'm kindda new to c# and i was looking for some ideas on 2 thing. I have looked far and wide for answers but haven't found an answer to my exact problem.

1. I have a byte array (called BA) within a for loop which keeps over-writting itself and there is no way for my to be able print it as a whole array. Is there a way to export it outside the for loop (maybe with a different name) so i can use it later on in the program? i just want something like this:

   ```
   byte[] BA2 = {3 187,3 203,111 32, ...etc}; //(groups of 2bytes separated by commas).
   ```

   From the original

   ```
   string hexValues = "03 BB,03 CB,6F 20,57 6F,72 6C,64 21";
   ```

   (and also to represent this information in bits (boolean) so {00000011 10111011,00000011 11001011, ...etc})
2. The second thing i must do is to shift these two bytes by 4 and apply and AND gate with FFF0 (which is the same as multiplying the first byte * 1, and the second by 0xF0). Then put this in a ushort[ ] (unsigned short array) which holds the transformed bytes in binary format and then from there convert it back to HEX.

I understand that this might be unclear (my code is kind of messy), and pretty complex. but i was hoping some of you c# guru's could lend me hand.

Here's my code so far, i have put in comments the bits that don't work so the code runs. but i desperatly need to fix them.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string hexValues = "03 BB,03 CB,6F 20,57 6F,72 6C,64 21";
        string[] hex2byte = hexValues.Split(',');

        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n2 byte String is: "+ hex2byte[j]);
            string[] hex1byte = hex2byte[j].Split(' ');

            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("byte " + hex1byte[k]);
                byte[] BA = StringToByteArray((hex1byte[k]));

                //bool[] AA = BitConverter.ToBoolean(BA);           // I'm essentially stuck here. I need somehting which actually works.

                //for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++);                   // This is my attemp to perform de shift and AND.
                //{
                //    ushort[] X = new ushort[1];
                //    X[0] = (ushort)((ushort)(BA[0] << 4) + (ushort)((BA[1] & 0xF0) >> 4));        // They have to be in this order: ((1stByte & 0xFF) << 4) + ((2byte & 0xF0) >> 4); first to the left then the right.

                //}

                Console.WriteLine("Converted " + BA[0]);
            }
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(BA[4]);               // it says: Does not exist in current context. Can it only b accesed in the for loop?
        Console.ReadKey();

    }   // Main method finishes.


    // Define StringToByteArray method.
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have two hex values, then you don´t have BYTEs, this are SHORTs

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: Not quite, it is `ushort`. `byte` is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string[] hexValues = new string[] { "03BB", "03CB", "6F20", "576F", "726C", "6421" };
ushort result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hexValues.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2 byte String is {0}", hexValues[i]);
    result = ushort.Parse(hexValues[i], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    Console.WriteLine("converted: {0}", result.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("converted: {0}", result.ToString("x")); // "x" format in ToString -> very useful for creating hex strings.
}
```

For your shifting you can use the << and >> operators, and | and & for bitwise operations.

Comment: This works, however, you are treating the 2 bytes together, my aim was to separate them into 2, because when i perform the shift, the first byte gets moved to the left and the second to the right.

So for example: 03 BB
this is 955 in dec, and 00000011 10111011 in bin. However, what i was looking for is (00000011<<4)+((10111011 & 11110000)>>4).
So as a sum between the two terms rather than a continuous 4byte number (if that makes sense).
After the shift, this would result in 00110000+00001011=00111011 or 48+11=59 in decimal.

But for now I'm gonna work using your code :) thanks for the reply!